# Como obter a lista de dispositivos conectados à rede

Tags: java, redes

Tenho a necessidade de encontrar os dispositivos conectados à rede em que meu programa executa. É uma rede via WiFi (não sei se isso muda a dificuldade da coisa), onde sei que existem ao menos dois dispositivos conectados ao roteador.

Alguém sabe se é possível fazer isso em Java? Talvez via multicast? (pergunto do multicast porque no roteador existe a informação de que há um grupo multicast configurado com o endereço `239.255.255.250`).

Comment: Lucas, não sei exatamente como fazer (por isso não consigo ajudar) pois nunca lidei com lookup de DNS local. Achei uma pergunta no SO EN que pode te ajudar a começar a esboçar a solução: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198669/any-way-to-discover-android-devices-on-your-network. A pergunta esta muito ampla. Sugiro começar a implementar e a qualquer dúvida realizar uma nova pergunta com o código que já fez.

Comment: Essa semana mesmo estou precisando fazer algo parecido, agradeço o Luiz pela edição, eu já estava quase criando uma pergunta aqui.

Comment: @re22 Eu achei a pergunta bacana e merecedora da edição. Fico feliz que possivelmente vá ajudar a mais pessoas. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Um bom ponto de partida deve ser esse projeto, escrito em java :

> **Android network tool: Discover hosts and scan their ports, in your
>   Wifi/3G network.**
>   https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery

***Funcionalidades***

- Descoberta de dispositivos em rede local (connect/ping discovery, dns discovery)
- Escaner de portas TCP (connect() scan)
- banco de dados NIC
- Exportação de resultados para o SDCard em XML
- Acesso as configurações de Wifi
- Velocidade de Scan adaptativo (inicio lento, então se adapta a latência da rede)
- Open Source

Uma alternativa simples de implementação também seria *pingar* (ICMP) todos os dispositivos da sua subrede, como no exemplo usando o `java.net.InetAddress`:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class NetworkPing {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        // uso de IPv4 e assumido!
        byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 254; i++) {
            ip[3] = (byte) i;
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
            if (address.isReachable(1000)) {
                System.out.println(address + " maquina esta ligada e pode ser pingada");
            } else if (!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName())) {
                System.out.println(address + " maquina reconhecida por um DNSLookup");
            } else {
                System.out.println(address + " o endereço de host e o nome do host são iguais, o host name não pode ser resolvido.");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

código fonte obtido em: http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-networking/6739-how-get-list-all-computers-my-network-computers-connected-me.html.

Complementando a minha resposta, com relação a você tentar uma descoberta dos dispositivos da rede tentando explorar usando o [endereço de multicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address), acho uma abordagem mais complicada, ele é designado para comunicação usando [datagramas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/definition.html), ou seja não existe uma conexão estabelecida e não existirá uma resposta ([acknowledgment](http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/jun/7/understanding-tcp-sequence-acknowledgment-numbers/)) do protocolo do seu recebimento. 
Voce consegue explorar o Multicasting e os Datagramas no java usando as apis  [DatagramSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html), [DatagramPacket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html) e [MulticastSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html). 
**Documentação de referencia da oracle usando datagramas**: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html

**UDP PortScanner:**
https://code.google.com/p/portscanner/source/browse/trunk/PortScanner/src/UDPScanner.java

Answer (score 11):

Eu vou abordar e descrever métodos que utilizo para conseguir informações de equipamentos conectados em rede wifi, sem dúvida o `ping` é uma alternativa, mas se o dispositivo estiver com algum firewall ou anti-vírus que bloqueie pacotes `ICMP`, você nunca terá retorno, o mesmo acontece para qualquer tipo de Scan que tente varrer sua rede, além de ser lento tem grandes chances de ter algum equipamento navegando em sua rede na qual o scan não consiga pegar.

A maneira mais segura de trazer informações corretas é ir direto na fonte (ou seja seu router),  você pode habilitar consultas via [SNMP](http://www.ti-redes.com/gerenciamento/snmp/intro/) em seu roteador/access point, eu acredito ser muito raro um equipamento de rede que não tenha essa opção hoje em dia, desta maneira você consegue consultar qualquer informação distribuída pelo equipamento, tais como consumo de banda, utilização de CPU, memória utilizada e é bem provável que algum `OID` (é o identificador, um número que colhe informação para uma determinada necessidade) retorne uma lista de endereços MACs dos equipamentos conectados a ele.

Segue um exemplo real da utlização:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c senhaSNMPAQUI 192.168.1.214 enterprises.171.11.37.4.4.5.2.1.2.1

SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.171.11.37.4.4.5.2.1.2.1.1 = Hex-STRING: 2X V6 98 XX XX XX
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.171.11.37.4.4.5.2.1.2.1.2 = Hex-STRING: A1 52 66 XX XX XX
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.171.11.37.4.4.5.2.1.2.1.3 = Hex-STRING: 51 SF 6D XX XX XX
```

É claro eu peguei as informações neste exemplo utilizando um client unix chamado `snmpwalk`, os parâmetros serão sempre a `versão` do SNMP a `comunity`  (tipo uma senha para acesso), o endereço `IP` do seu router e o `OID` que traz a informação que você precisa, cada equipamento possui OIDs específicos e na maioria das vezes você vai precisar pegar estas informações em documentações providas pelo fabricante, para o meu Dlink aqui o `OID` que traz as informações de equipamentos conectados a ele é o `enterprises.171.11.37.4.4.5.2.1.2.1`, OK você pode fazer o mesmo utilizando libs em java para fazer consulta snmp, acredito que vá encontrar várias, uma delas e com exemplo é [SNMP4J](https://sites.google.com/site/mullais/logic/java/how-to-run-a-simple-snmp-get-program-using-java-with-eclipse). Ai você me pergunta no seu exemplo tem três equipamentos conectados, como eu sei o `IP` deles ?

Uma das maneiras é enviar um `broadcast` na rede e pegar o retorno da tabela `arp`

```
arp -a

? (192.168.1.11) at A1 52 66 XX XX XX on eth0 expires in 931 seconds [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.52) at 2X V6 98 XX XX XX on eth0 expires in 1169 seconds [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.17) at 51 SF 6D XX XX XX on eth0 expires in 650 seconds [ethernet]
```

Meu equipamento é china e não tem SNMP ou nao tem OID's SNMP que tragam as informações que eu precise e agora?

Habilite no seu router algum método de acesso remoto (ssh, telnet), se conecte no equipamento e descubra algum comando dentro dele que pegue as informações que você precise

Outro exemplo real:

```
telnet 192.168.2.1
Trying 192.168.2.1...
Connected to 192.168.2.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
login: usuariodorouter
Password: ******
WAP-> get clientinfo
Client1--time:1424
Client1--ssid: primary SSID
Client1--mac:CW:45:67:XX:XX:XX
Client1--auth:OPEN
Client1--rssi:11
Client1--mode:11n
Client1--psmode:0
Client1--rx_bytes:234239
Client1--tx_bytes:285309
```

Neste exemplo foi feita uma conexão via telnet no router e rodei o comando `get clientinfo`, mais uma vez você vai precisar consultar algum doc do fabricante para saber qual comando retorna o que você precisa, em java também existem libs de client telnet que fazem essa conexão e iteração para envio de comandos, tudo o que tem que fazer é colher os dados...